# Combine 2 select statements with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Hey all I have the following 2 SQL query's:

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_NAME 
FROM 
  Exceltest.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables 
WHERE 
  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Which produces:

```
'AC Technician$'
'Drafting$'
'IT Tech$'
'Maintenance$'
'Carpentry$'
'Masonry$'
'Exercise$'
```

And the 2nd query:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(TABLE_NAME) AS rollcount 
FROM 
  Exceltest.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables 
WHERE 
  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Which gives me the value of **7** which is correct.

Now I wish to combine both of these into one query. I've tried:

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_NAME 
FROM 
  Exceltest.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables 
WHERE 
  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
UNION
SELECT 
  COUNT(TABLE_NAME) AS rollcount 
FROM 
  Exceltest.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables 
WHERE 
  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

But I get the error of:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ''AC Technician$'' to data type int.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the output in same column:

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_NAME 
FROM 
  Exceltest.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables 
WHERE 
  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

UNION

SELECT 
  CAST(COUNT(TABLE_NAME) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS rollcount 
FROM 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables 
WHERE 
  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Comment: Not quite correct but using your second SELECT I was able to combine it with my first SELECT and that worked. Thanks Pinwar13! Correct edit made to your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
TABLE_NAME 
FROM 
Exceltest.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables 
WHERE 
TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
UNION
SELECT 
CAST(COUNT(TABLE_NAME) AS VARCHAR(50)) AS TABLE_NAME 
FROM 
Exceltest.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables 
WHERE 
TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_NAME, 
  (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(TABLE_NAME) AS rollcount 
    FROM 
      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables 
    WHERE 
      TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
  ) AS Cnt
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
WHERE 
  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE';


+----------------------------------------------------+------+
| TABLE_NAME                                         | Cnt  |
+----------------------------------------------------+------+
| ARCHIVE_GLOBAL_STATUS                              |   95 |
| HISTO_GLOBAL_STATUS                                |   95 |
| HISTO_SAVE                                         |   95 |
| PurgeInfo                                          |   95 |
| Stats                                              |   95 |

....

| socket_summary_by_instance                         |   95 |
| table_io_waits_summary_by_index_usage              |   95 |
| table_io_waits_summary_by_table                    |   95 |
| table_lock_waits_summary_by_table                  |   95 |
| threads                                            |   95 |
| users                                              |   95 |
+----------------------------------------------------+------+
95 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```